# Seeking AVHRR NDVI data for NE India?

Tags: data, india

I'm looking for NDVI data 1 km res. of AVHRR for North East India. The data does not seems to be available in USGS. It only shows the US region.

I have no idea about AVHRR.

If the data is available for NE India then how do I download it?

Comment: If this is open data then the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The data which I was looking for, I found it [here](https://www.vito-eodata.be/PDF/portal/Application.html#Home)

**Vito Earth Observation**, It also has data such as **PROBA-V 1 KM PRODUCTS NEAR REAL-TIME,

PROBA-V SEGMENTS, 300m and 100m, SPOT-VEGETATION, SENTINEL 1 and 2, METOP-AVHRR S10 SYNTHESES, ENVISAT-MERIS S10 SYNTHESES**.